# Adding link to SSRS for sub report in AX2012

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Suppose 4 people in a firm voted to one employee.  I have already displayed it in my SSRS report as
    EMP1  ->        4
Now, I want 4 to be hyperlinked so that when someone clicks on it another report opens with
names of those 4 people who voted along with their comments. In this report I am using query as a dataset.

Kindly assist me on how to approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the screen cast [Adding Report Drill Through Actions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHeJFxdYS6Y) from [Dynamics AX BI Videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/dynamicsaxbi).

Comment: thanks for your assistance. I found few links too which i am adding [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc653599.aspx)